# Redirect old URLs and avoid 404s

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My old urls was

```
http://site.com/news/183/Blue+Lagoon
```

and this is htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
```

Now im change url structure and my url is like

```
http://site.com/news/183
```

and line in htaccess is

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/([^/]{0,32})?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L,NC]
```

Now i have 404 error when users come from google on my site , also google webmaster tools report me about this error, how i can redirect old url to new one with htaccess...

Comment: That last rule works fine for me for a URL like `http://site.com/news/183`

Comment: Yes works okey for url http://site.com/news/183 but when you go to http://site.com/news/183/Blue+Lagoon have error 404, i need to redirect http://site.com/news/183/Blue+Lagoon to new one http://site.com/news/183